# One-liner to sort and uniq two outputs

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, pipe, io-redirection

I'm currently doing this to `sort` and `uniq` the output of two different commands:

```
tshark -r sample.pcap -T fields -e eth.src -e ip.src > hello
tshark -r sample.pcap -T fields -e eth.dst -e ip.dst >> hello
sort < hello | uniq > hello_uniq
```

In a nutshell, I'm outputting source MAC addresses and IPs into a file. I'm then appending destination MAC addresses and IPs to that same file.

I then `sort` the file and input that into `uniq` to end up with a list of unique MAC to IP address mapping.

Is there a way to do this in one line?

(Note: the use of `tshark` is not really relevant here, my question applies to any two sources of output like that)

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`sort` can take multiple input files (and has a built-in `uniq` equivalent `-u`). Combine that with a fancy `bash` [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to result in:

`sort -u <(tshark -r sample.pcap -T fields -e eth.src -e ip.src) <(tshark -r sample.pcap -T fields -e eth.dst -e ip.dst) > hello_uniq`

Answer (score 2):

`(tshark -r sample.pcap -T fields -e eth.src -e ip.src; tshark -r sample.pcap -T fields -e eth.dst -e ip.dst) | sort | uniq > hello_uniq`

Comment: To "teach a man to fish," I'll note that the `()` put the commands together into a subshell, which combined their output.